# Global variable remains unchanged after alteration in methods

Tags: java, android, methods, onclick, global-variables

I am currently facing a minor challenge where I am unable to acquire changes made to global variable (fileName) outside of the method that altered it (startRecording()).

What happens now: fileName remains null after alteration by startRecording()

What i want is: To acquire fileName inside userRecordButton's onClick

It looks like a basic issue, but I cant solve it, will be so helpful to get some quick help. Thank you in advance.

p/s: This is just parts of code that I feel relevant, please notify me if you would need the full code.

**Code**

```
    public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> { 
public String mFileName = null;

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final Button userRecordButton = (Button)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.recordButton);

userRecordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {      
                    if (!isRecording) {
                        userRecordButton.setText("Ready?");
                        Handler delayRecord = new Handler();
                      //This is where i called the handler
                        setDelayedRecord(delayRecord, userPlayButton, userRecordButton);

            //The issue is here: it shows null when i tried debugging
                        String whatIsMyFileName = mFileName;

                        Handler maximumRecord = new Handler();
                        setMaximumRecord(maximumRecord, userPlayButton, userRecordButton);
                    } else {
                        exeStopRecording(userPlayButton, userRecordButton);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

} //End of getView

    public void setDelayedRecord(Handler handler, final Button userPlayBtnReference, final Button userRecordBtnReference) {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //James!, this is where I called start recorder.
                    startRecording();
                    userPlayBtnReference.setEnabled(false);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.d("Hello", "Problem in start recording", e);
                }
                userRecordBtnReference.setText("Stop");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Started Recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setPathName(mFileName);
            }
        }, 500);
    }

 private void startRecording() {

        mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), mFolder_main);
        if (!mFile.exists()) {
            mFile.mkdirs();
        }

        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd'-'HHmmssSSS");
        currentTime_1 = new Date();
        dateString = formatter.format(currentTime_1);
        uniqueName = "Pronunce-" + dateString + ".3gp";
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/" + mFolder_main + "/" + uniqueName;
    //mFileName should no longer be null    

        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
        isRecording = true;
        mRecorder.start();
    }

}//End of wordAdapter
```

Comment: What is userRecordButton? where did u initialize userRecordButton?

Comment: Hi @Raghavendra, it is initialized inside getView

Comment: okay, did u debug? whether that line is executing or not? Where u r setting the value

Comment: @Raghavendra, yes, i did, it returns null upon debugging. The value is altered in startRecording method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a global variable, mFileName which has been set to null. You then move into the event handler and set a new local variable, whatIsMyFileName to the value of the global variable, null. At no point in the event handler do call any method that would change the value of the local or global variable.

Comment: Hello, @James Marshall, first of all, thank you for responding. Inside my event handler, I called a method startRecording(). I have altered the value of mFileName 3 times inside of startRecording method. Since WhatIsMyFileName initialization code is below SetDelayedRecord, isnt that supposed to change the value of mFileName from null?

Comment: With the code you have provided above the method startRecording() is not called inside your event handler (check your brackets).

Comment: I have updated my explanation. Hope that helps. Do you think it would be appropriate to just show the full code, its quite long tho.

Comment: I see where it is being called now. The issue here is that neither method is returning anything. Check this answer:

[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887099/modify-a-global-variable-with-a-function

Comment: Agreed, that is a great solution,thanks. The main reason I posted this question was because I was wondering why the global variable was not modified directly since some of my other global variables (all booleans) are used in the same manner and I altered their values, which shows up in getView and other methods. This made me wonder if I am not using correct syntax or practice. Yesterday, I have edited the code to pass information into the method as solution. Anyhow, thank you so much for your effort, @Marshall.

Comment: No probs, happy coding!